# Отправка IFormCollection через httpClient c#

Tags: c#, .net-core, httpclient, formdata

Я пишу проект на `asp.net Core` и у меня есть задача передать форму на удаленный сервер. Тип формы `multipart/form-data`

В своем конроллере я ее получаю в виде объекта:

`IFormCollection form = Request.Form`

Далее мне ее нужно отправить на сервер через `HttpClient`.

`httpClient.Post("endpoint", {httpContent})`

Не могу понять как `form` привести к `{httpContent}`

Подскажите правильное решение, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вам требуется дальше отправить такую же форму, то используйте `FormUrlEncodedContent`

```
IFormCollection form = Request.Form;

using var client = new HttpClient();
var response = await client.PostAsync("endpoint", new FormUrlEncodedContent(
    form
        .Select(e => e.Key)
        .ToDictionary(k => k, v => form[v].ToString())
    ));
```

Comment: спасибо, Вам, добрый человек.